# Gamma Function Question

Tags: gamma-function

I am relatively new to this idea. What values can use for x for the gamma function? For example would all complex numbers work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the integral representation

$$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$$

You will find that it only converges if the real part of $x$ is greater than zero.  That is, for $x=a+bi$, we must have $a>0$, which is due to comparison with the p-series around $t=0$.

To extend to all complex values, use

$$\Gamma(x-1)=\frac{\Gamma(x)}{x-1}$$

with the exception that $x\notin\{0,-1,-2,\dots\}$, since clearly we will run into things like

$$\Gamma(0)=\frac{\Gamma(1)}0=\text{undefined}$$

---

For representations of the Gamma function that converge for all $x\notin\{0,-1,-2,\dots\}$, see the [wikipedia.](http://$x%5Cnotin%5C%7B0,-1,-2,%5Cdots%5C%7D$)

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Simple Art, it can be defined as
$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}\mathrm e^{-z}\,\mathrm d\mkern 1mu t$$
for all $z$ with $\;\operatorname{Re} z>0$.

Then one can show this function has an *analytic continuation* on $\mathbf C\smallsetminus\{0,-1,\dots,-n,\dots\}$ which satisfies the functional relation:
$$\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z).$$

*Note*: 
It also can be defined as 
$$\Gamma(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!\,n^z}{z(z+1)\dotsm(z+n)}\qquad\qquad\text{ (Euler's definition)}$$
and as the infinite product:
$$\Gamma(z)=\frac{\mathrm e^{-\gamma z}}{z}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm e^{\tfrac zn}}{1+\dfrac zn}\qquad\qquad\text{(Weierstraß' definition)}$$
where $\gamma$ is *Euler-Mascheroni's* constant.